# Trouble in DOSBox: [ MOV SI, (160 * height)]?

Tags: assembly, dosbox

In the following code I have commented with asterisks the line that I am having trouble with. As you can see, SI contains (160 * 8). That is the correct value, however, I need to change it so that instead of it being (160 * 8), it should be (160 * height). Height is declared in the data segment as a DB. I understand that I cannot say (160 * height) but could somebody please help me solve this issue? I just need to store the correct value in SI. Thank you

```
MyData SEGMENT

    singleLine DB 0DAh, 0CFh, 0C0h, 0D9h, 0C4h, 0B3h
    doubleLine DB 0CAh, 0BBh, 0C8h, 0BCh, 0CDh, 0BAh

    ulCorner EQU 0
    urCorner EQU 1
    blCorner EQU 2
    brCorner EQU 3
    horLine EQU 4
    verLine EQU 5

    singleOrDouble DB 1
    foreground DB 0001
    background DB 0011
    height DB 8
    startCorner DW 1512

MyData ENDS                       

;------------------------------------------------------------------------    CODE SEGMENT
MyCode SEGMENT
        ASSUME CS:MyCode, DS:MyData   

MainProg  PROC                

    MOV     AX, MyData             
    MOV     DS, AX                 
    MOV     AX, 0B800h         
    MOV     ES, AX

    CALL drawBox   

    MOV     AH, 4Ch                
    INT     21h                   

MainProg ENDP 

drawBox  PROC
   MOV AH, foreground
   MOV AL, singleLine + ulCorner
   MOV BX, startCorner
   MOV ES:[BX], AX
   MOV AL, singleLine + blCorner 
   MOV SI, 160 * 8   ;*****************height = 8********************
   MOV ES:[BX + SI], AX
   RET
drawBox ENDP

MyCode ENDS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load a value from memory into a register like `ax`, with `mov`, and you can multiply a register with a constant value with `mul` or `imul`.

You can also transfer between registers with `mov` or, on the off-chance that's not available between two specific registers, something like `push ax; pop si`.

So, though it's been many years since I've done x86 assembler, this would be where I'd start:

```
push ax             ; Save registers we're using.
push bx

xor  ax, ax         ; Get height value.
mov  al, [height]

mov  bx, 160        ; Multiply by 160.
mul  bx

push ax             ; Copy to SI.
pop  si

pop  bx             ; Restore registers.
pop  ax
```

You can pump something similar into `nasm`, but multiplying by three rather than a hundred and sixty (because the exit code is limited):

```
section .text
    global _start
_start:
    push ax             ; Save registers.
    push bx

    xor  ax, ax         ; Get height value (8).
    mov  al, [height]

    mov  bx, 3          ; Triple.
    mul  bx

    push ax             ; Move to SI.
    pop  si

    pop  bx             ; Restore registers.
    pop  ax

    xor  ebx, ebx       ; Return result as exit code
    push si
    pop  bx
    mov eax, 1
    int 0x80

section .data
height db 8
```

Assembling, linking and running that code, then checking the exit value gives you the correct result, `8 * 3 = 24`:

```
pax$ nasm -f elf demo.asm
pax$ ld -m elf_i386 -s -o demo demo.o
pax$ ./demo ; echo $?
24
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I am aware of MOV and MUL and all that, I've been playing around with them for the past hour and I just can't get it to work, I'm already using AX to hold the character to put on the screen and I'm already using BX to hold the starting location, if you know what I could do could you please tell me? Thank you.